# Identify types of Pandas DataFrame columns numpy array of DataFrame values

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe, types

I'm writing glue code connecting libraries that use Pandas DataFrames and Numpy arrays, and I'm running into some problems determining which columns are 'object/string' in Numpy arrays which are originally created from Pandas Dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["one", "two", "three"]})
test_arr = test.values
test_df2 = pd.DataFrame(test_arr)

test_df.dtypes
# a     int64, b    object

test_df2.dtypes

# 0    object, 1    object
```

I would expect test_df2.dtypes to be int64 & object rather than both object.

How can I find the datatypes of original Pandas DataFrame columns using the information in the numpy array 'test_arr'?

I can achieve the desired behaviour using the following approach, but am wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant solution? I'm also worried this approach might be brittle:

```
test_df3 = pd.DataFrame(test_arr).apply(
lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors="ignore"), axis=1
)
```

EDIT - a few solutions using datatypes of test_df. I don't have access to this, or control over how test_arr is created. I want to find datatypes of test_df using ONLY test_arr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of `test_df2` columns with `test_df` dtypes and use that dictionary in [`df.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

```
d = dict(zip(test_df2.columns,[*test_df.dtypes]))
#{0: dtype('int64'), 1: dtype('O')}
final = test_df2.astype(dict(zip(test_df2.columns,[*test_df.dtypes])))
```

---

```
print(final.dtypes)
0     int64
1    object
dtype: object
```

there is another builtin called [`infer_objects`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) *which attempts to infer better dtypes for object columns*:

```
final1 = test_df2.astype(object).infer_objects()
print(final1.dtypes)
```

---

```
0     int64
1    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: I can't access test_df

Comment: @oli5679 did you also try `infer_objects` (The 2nd proposed method) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like that:

```
import pandas as pd
test_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": ["one", "two", "three"]})
test_arr = test_df.to_numpy()
test_df2 = pd.DataFrame(test_arr, columns = test_df.columns).astype(test_df.dtypes)
```

Note that in pandas documentation better use .to_numpy() instead of .values as mentoined in this [pandas_docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

Comment: I'm using external libraries that convert my data frame to array ans can't access test_df